# How to create a hole in the box in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit to create a 3D Room for a Swift iOS app.

I'm using multiple boxes and placing it together to create different walls of the room. I want to also add doors and windows to the room for which I need to cut holes into the walls. This looks like a very common scenario but yet I couldn't find any relevant answers out there.

I know there are multiple ways of doing it -

1. Simplest being, don't cut the box. Place another box with door or wall texture.

   - But I do want to keep a light source outside of the room and want it to flow into the room through these doors and windows
2. Create multiple boxes for single wall and put them together to make a geometry

   - My last resort maybe.
3. Create custom geometry.

   - Feels too complicated since it requires me to draw each triangle myself. Not sure?

But what I was actually expecting -

1. Subtract geometries from geometries?
2. Library that's already handling these complexities?

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scene kit offers some awesome potential but it's not a substitute for a 3D modeling program. If you want something much beyond assembling with primitives and extrusion in a plane you should think about constructing your model in a dedicated 3-D package and exporting the model into SceneKit as a .dae file. You might take a look at Blender. It's free and readily available on the net. I suspect it can easily do what you want and the learning curve will be compensated by the higher level functions of a graphics program versus coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think @bpedit described the best approach.

A weak second choice would be to use SCNShape to build your geometry. That still leaves you the problem of constructing a Bezier path that matches your wall layout/topology. That might be a helpful hack in the short term, to save you from an immediate learning curve in modeling software. But I predict you'll still eventually move to a tool like Blender, SketchUp, Cheetah 3D, or Maya.